# Download WRB soil groups

Tags: download, soilgrids

Downloading data via the new soilgrids.org is working nicely for all layered information, but not for WRB classification. I tested it at different PC and different browsers, but it always gives this error message:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport version="2.0.1" xml:lang="en-US" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="ExtentError" locator="extent">
<ows:ExceptionText>
msWCSGetCoverage20(): WCS server error. Raster size out of range, width and height of resulting coverage must be no more than MAXSIZE=8192
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

The request being made is:

```
https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wrb.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.0.1&REQUEST=GetCoverage&COVERAGEID=MostProbable&FORMAT=image/tiff&SUBSET=long(0,2)&SUBSET=lat(0,2)&SUBSETTINGCRS=http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326&OUTPUTCRS=http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/152160
```

Would be interesting to know if this is an error due to my hard-/software or a general problem (and how to solve it).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: It looks like you are making an invalid WCS request but please [edit] your question to tell us which client you are using and how you are making the request

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a look and the error and reasons why are rather interresting:

Doing a Describe Coverage: `https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/wrb.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.0.1&REQUEST=DescribeCoverage&COVERAGEID=MostProbable`

We have a envelope like this:

```
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Envelope srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/152160" axisLabels="long lat" uomLabels="deg deg" srsDimension="2">
<gml:lowerCorner>-180 -61.0674762500609</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>186.933274624154 83.999167206</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>
</gml:boundedBy>
```

This is incorrect: `srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/152160"`

The map file has the following:

```
    EXTENT -180.0 -61.06747625006139 179.9999424001524 83.99916720600001
    PROJECTION
        'init=epsg:4326'
    END #PROJECTION
:
:
    LAYER
        NAME "MostProbable"

        PROJECTION
            'init=epsg:4326'
        END #PROJECTION

        EXTENT -180.0 -61.06747625006139 179.9999424001524 83.99916720600001
        METADATA
            'ows_title' 'WRB most probable class'
            'wcs_label' 'MostProbable'
            'wcs_rangeset_name' 'range1'
            'wcs_rangeset_label' 'label1'
            'ows_extent' '-180.0 -61.06747625006139 179.9999424001524 83.9991672$
            'ows_srs' 'EPSG:152160 EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857 EPSG:54009 EPSG:54012 EPS$
            'ows_abstract' ''
            'ows_keywordlist' ''
            'wcs_formats' 'GEOTIFF_BYTE'
:
:
```

The issue is on 'ows_srs' that has `EPSG:152160` as 1st SRS and therefore will use it to populate the envelope information

Change things the  `ows_srs` to `'ows_srs' 'EPSG:4326 EPSG:152160 EPSG:3857 EPSG:54009 EPSG:54012'` has fixed thing

(maps file was update upon writiting of answer)